# Improve on MySQL LIKE operator

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a search form using a single text input with PHP, MySQLi.

Users search for names of people. In the MySQL table is a column 'name' and also a column 'nameNoSpaces' - this value is used when matching a user's search.

On input, the users query is stripped of all whitespace so that it also has no spaces. then I use the LIKE operator to compare the user's input (with no spaces) to the column 'nameNoSpaces'.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE nameNoSpaces LIKE '%query%'
```

If a value in 'nameNoSpaces' contains any part of the query string, it will be matched.

E.G. query 'hello you' will be matched to the value 'goodhelloyou'.
But not : query 'you hello'

I want to improve the search capabilities so that 'you hello' will return the row containing 'goodhelloyou'.

I have achieved this with PHP (foreach word do 'LIKE '%word%' and return all names that match every word).

BUT I was wondering if there is simply a SQL operator I can use to achieve this??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE nameNoSpaces LIKE '%hello%you%'
```

Comment: %hello%you% will match 'hellogoodyou' but %you%hello% won't..which is what I need

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...should of seen it before

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%word1%' AND name LIKE '%word2%'....'%wordn%'
```

put all words into an array and use a foreach loop to create the query

Comment: I wasn't using the foreach loop to create a single SELECT query - I was running a SELECT query for each word, using a foreach loop